# Asymptotic behavior of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{b^n}$ when $x\to1^-$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics

This follow my previous post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3091682/proving-that-lim-limits-x-to-1-frac1-ln1-x-sum-limits-n-0-inft/3091778#3091778), where Song has proven that $\forall b>1,\lim\limits_{x\to 1^{-}}\frac{1}{\ln(1-x)}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{b^n}=-\frac{1}{\ln(b)}$, that is to say :
$$\forall b>1,\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{b^n}=-\log_b(1-x)+o_{x\to1^-}\left(\log_b(1-x)\right)$$
(The $o_{x\to1^-}\left(\log_b(1-x)\right)$ representing a function that is asymptotically smaller than $\log_b(1-x)$ when $x\to1^{-}$, that is to say whose quotient by $\log_b(1-x)$ converges to $0$ as $x\to1^{-}$, see [small o notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation))

So we have here a first asymptotic approximation of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{b^n}$.

I now want to take it one step further and refine the asymptotic behaviour, by proving a stronger result which I conjecture to be true (backed by numerical simulations) :
$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{b^n}=-\log_b(1-x)+O_{x\to1^-}\left(1\right)$$

(The $O_{x\to1^-}\left(1\right)$ representing a function that is asymptotically bounded when $x\to1^-$, see [big o notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation))

In other words, we want to go from :

"this sum is $-\log_b(1-x)$ + something that is asymptotically smaller than $\log_b(1-x)$ when $x\to1^-$"

to :

"this sum is $-\log_b(1-x)$ + something that is asymptotically bounded when $x\to1^-$"

And since $\log_b(1-x)$ diverges to $-\infty$ when $x\to1^-$, this is indeed a much more precise evaluation of the asymptotic behaviour !

Now, the way to go would be to show that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{b^n}+\log_b(1-x)$ is asymptotically bounded when $x\to1^-$, that is to say that $\exists M>0, \exists x_0\in\left(0,1\right) \text{ such that }\forall x\in\left[x_0,1\right), \left|\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{b^n}+\log_b(1-x)\right|\leqslant M$.

And to be honest, I'm kind of stuck. Any suggestion ?

Comment: You may be interested in [MSE question 2864987](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2864987) "What's the limit of $\log_2(1-x) + x + x^2 + x^4 + x^8 ...$" which is a special case where $b=2$.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this was almost done in my [previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3091682/proving-that-lim-limits-x-to-1-frac1-ln1-x-sum-limits-n-0-inft/3091778#3091778). I've shown that
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n\ge 0}e^{-b^n \lambda}&=&
-\frac{\ln \lambda}{\ln b}+O(1)
\end{eqnarray}$$ where $e^{-\lambda}=x$. Thus
$$
\sum_{n\ge 0}x^{b^n} =-\log_b (-\log x) +O(1).
$$ It remains to show that
$$
-\log_b (-\log x)=-\log_b (1-x)+O(1) 
$$ as $x\to 1^-$. This follows from
$$
-\log_b (-\log x)+\log_b (1-x)=-\log_b\left(\frac{-\log x}{1-x}\right)\xrightarrow[]{x\to 1^-}0.
$$ I hope this will help.

Comment: In this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296066/evaluate-lim-x-to1-left-sum-n-0-infty-leftx2n-right-log-2-f/2869547#2869547 I proved that the $O(1)$ is oscillating when $x\rightarrow 1-$.

Comment: @i707107 Very nice argument! (+1)